# 403 after login with OAuth 2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring Security 5 and I implemented the login but everytime I try to call other URL after login I get a `403 Unhautorized`. My `doFilterInternal` is not even called (it is for the login though).

It gets on `org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter#doFilter` but it has no security context or authentication present neither a session.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers( "/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository

```
@Component
public class HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository implements AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {
    public static final String OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_COOKIE_NAME = "oauth2_auth_request";
    public static final String REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME = "redirect_uri";
    private static final int cookieExpireSeconds = 180;

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest loadAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return CookieUtils.getCookie(request, OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_COOKIE_NAME)
                .map(cookie -> CookieUtils.deserialize(cookie, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.class))
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (authorizationRequest == null) {
            CookieUtils.deleteCookie(request, response, OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_COOKIE_NAME);
            CookieUtils.deleteCookie(request, response, REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME);
            return;
        }

        CookieUtils.addCookie(response, OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_COOKIE_NAME, CookieUtils.serialize(authorizationRequest), cookieExpireSeconds);
        String redirectUriAfterLogin = request.getParameter(REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(redirectUriAfterLogin)) {
            CookieUtils.addCookie(response, REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME, redirectUriAfterLogin, cookieExpireSeconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return this.loadAuthorizationRequest(request);
    }

//    @Override
//    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
//        return this.loadAuthorizationRequest(request);
//    }

    public void removeAuthorizationRequestCookies(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        CookieUtils.deleteCookie(request, response, OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_COOKIE_NAME);
        CookieUtils.deleteCookie(request, response, REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question, maybe I am missing that step, I am using this https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo as a bases. But adapted to Spring Security 5. He just creates a bea with it as well.

Comment: You are right, I already made it work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the resource-server configuration in your HTTP config with either JWT decoder or token introspection ("opaqueToken" in spring security configuration DSL). Sample configuration from [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) I wrote:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http,
            Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter,
            ServerProperties serverProperties)
            throws Exception {

        // Enable OAuth2 with custom authorities mapping
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        // Enable and configure CORS
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf().disable();

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when
        // authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        });

        // Route security: authenticated to all routes but actuator and Swagger-UI
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/health/readiness", "/actuator/health/liveness", "/v3/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }
```

**OAuth2 login is for clients** (server side rendered UI with template engine like Thymeleaf or JSF) and **requires sessions** (and CSRF protection), **not for resource-servers** (REST APIs) which should respond to unauthorized requests to secured resources with 401 (unauthorized) and not 302 (redirect to login). Use a [certified OpenID client lib](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) in your client to manage redirection to authorization server, token acquisition and refreshing, and requests authorization (setting of Authorization header with access-token).

Answer (score 0):

You asked for `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` and it's what you get.
If there is no "state", there is no recording of the fact that the user has logged in successfully. It's a setup for REST services not for UI interaction.

Comment: I am doing a REST service.

Comment: OP tries to save the access token in a cookie instead of a session.